# Adding paragraph to div in js

Tags: javascript

why doesn't it work? i just want to add a paragraph to a div. Guys, why doesn't it work? i just want to add a paragraph to a div.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="pobieranko.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="klasa">lalal</div>


    
</body>
</html>



        const divek = document.querySelector(".klasa")
    const paragraf = document.createElement("p")
    paragraf.textContent = "paragrafik"
    
    divek.appendChild (paragraf);
```

Comment: It works fine, make sure that you add the `script` tag for the external js file.

Comment: Just to be sure....you put simplified code here, right? And you actually have <script> tags?

Comment: just add script tag

Answer (score 0):

It appears you did not add a script tag to the page as so:

```
<script>
const divek = document.querySelector(".klasa")
const paragraf = document.createElement("p")
paragraf.textContent = "paragrafik"
divek.appendChild (paragraf);
</script>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5I3rLyz